# First setTimeout function is not getting executed in js

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I'm trying to show different text in a modal box by setting a time interval with the help of `setTimeout` function in pure java script, however first `setTimeout` is skipped and second `setTimeout` is executed directly, not sure of exact reason

```js
function retry_emp(){

document.getElementById('error_text').innerHTML="Hold on...retrying  connection to server.It may take a while";
//This is not working setTimeout
    setTimeout(function(){

        document.getElementById('error_text').innerHTML="Still working.. It is taking longer than usual.";
    },7000);
    //This got executed directly
  setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('error_text').setAttribute("style", "color:#F44336;");
     document.getElementById('error_text').innerHTML="Its all broken, please contact HR department for to help you on these";
    },7000);    
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  
  
  <div id="error_profile" class="modal" role="dialog" style="display: none">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  
                    <h4 class="modal-title">INCIRCLE</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                 
                  <p id='error_text' style="text-align:left"><br>Something went wrong, retry submitting  or try again later.
                    </div>

               

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="retry_emp()">Retry</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
                 </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: both your setTimeout functions are operating on the same element, so with them both having a delay of 7000ms, the second one is going to overwrite the first faster than you can tell a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling javascript to execute the two functions "at the same time": 7 seconds after the call of retry_emp. In fact, there is a little time beetwen the two timeout function callings (some ms), and it is why you can only see the second result on your page.

Perhaps you would like to have the first function and then 7 seconds after it fire the second one ?

```
function retry_emp(){

document.getElementById('error_text').innerHTML="Hold on...retrying  connection to server.It may take a while";
//This is not working setTimeout
    setTimeout(function(){

        document.getElementById('error_text').innerHTML="Still working.. It is taking longer than usual.";
       //This got executed directly
      setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('error_text').setAttribute("style", "color:#F44336;");
         document.getElementById('error_text').innerHTML="Its all broken, please contact HR department for to help you on these";
        },7000); 
    },7000);

}
```

Comment: This works but it might be simpler to just make the duration of the second timeout 14000 instead of nesting them.

Comment: @DanielBeck I thought about it too, but if you want cancel somewhere in your code the timeout call of the first function, with my method, the second timeout function won't be called.